# Regular Expression replacement Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am modifying a json file for Rust with the Oxide mod and I am unfamiliar with programming in general.

I need to replace several instances of "stackable": 64.0, with "stackable": 15000.0,

The value is not always "64.0". There are instances of "1000.0" and "1.0" etc...

What I am currently doing is:

```
Search for: "stackable":/*/*/*/*
Replace with: "stackable": 15000.0,
```

This replaces the text that I want but essentially the end result is it simply enters the text in before the default value. So a line will end up looking like

```
"stackable": 15000.0, 64.,
```

How can I replace using wildcards but also remove the default value?

Answer (score 0):

First match "stackable" and then match spaces if any and then match numbers with `.` in them, using a character class.

```
Find: (stackable)\s*[\d.]+
Replace: $1: 15000.0
```